# cpi_walk_namespace failed

Tags: kernel, upgrade

I have just upgraded from kernel 4.9.x to kernel 4.12.5 and now when I boot one of the messages I get is "ibm acpi_walk_namespace failed"  I have not changed the config of the kernel.

What I want to know is; Where should I post this so that the right people get to see this message and so can work on it?

Thank you for your help.